# how to subtract elements within an array using for loops in python

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

I have an array `a = [4,3,2,1]`
What I am trying to achieve is that I need a single value on subtracting the elements in the array that is `4-3-2-1`.

I tried the below this using for loop but it does not seem to work. I don't seem to get the right value on execution.

```
def sub_num(arr):
    difference = arr[0]
    n = len(arr)
    print(n)
    print(i)
    for i in n: difference = arr[n] - arr[n-1]
    return(difference)
```

Comment: just basic subtraction of numbers , in this case the answer shoud be  -1

Comment: Should not `4 - 3 - 2 - 1` be `-2`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list `a`:

```
a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

And wish to get the result of `4 - 3 - 2 - 1`, you can use `functools.reduce`.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> reduce(int.__sub__, a)
-2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with nested lists:

```
b = sum([a[0],*[-x for x in a[1:]]])
```

**Simpler solution without `for`**:

Since `4-3-2-1` is equal to `4-(3+2+1)`:

```
a[0]-sum(a[1:])
```

Comment: This would be better with some elaboration as to how and why this works.

Answer (score -1):

You could modify your code like this

```
def sub_num(arr):
    difference = arr[0]
    n = len(arr)
    print(n)
    for i in range(1,n): 
        difference = difference - arr[i]
    return difference
```

Note:

1. Printing value of i without defining it is not possible

Comment: thanks you all fot the help.  was able to solve my issue